# Not able to pass objects using intent

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to download an object from the firebase firestore database and send it to an other activity. Here is my code:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Constants.COLLECTION)
                        .document(getCurrentUid()!!)
                        .get()
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            snapshot ->
                            val user: User? = snapshot.toObject(User::class.java)
                            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.USER_OBJECT, user)

                        }
```

but the problem is I am getting an error in `intent.putExtra(Constants.USER_OBJECT, user)`.

My User class implements serializable

What is wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android)

Comment: Make sure you include the error you're getting, otherwise we're all just guessing.

Comment: @Dharmaraj That doesn't answer my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is the Constant a String?

Otherwise you can try to cast your user to a Serializable and see if that fails, if it doesn't it should work.

So

```
   val user: User? = snapshot.toObject(User::class.java)
   val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
   intent.putExtra(Constants.USER_OBJECT, user as Serializable)
```

Make sure that user isn't null when passing it too. Maybe putExtra has been updated to only allow non-null values and your user might be null.

Comment: My error was that user should be nullable. But I don't know how to make user object as nullable. Constants.USER_OBJECT is a string